# StdAudio class makes my JFrame not display

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to write a program that plays musical chords. I'd like to add a window that shows a progress bar displaying the time that the chords play for and how much they have completed. To play the chords, I've been using a slightly modified version of the [StdAudio class](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdAudio.java.html). So far, I have the following code to be run when I ask a chord to play.

```
public static void playNotes(double[] frequencies, double duration, double amplitude)
{
    PlayAudioGUI g = new PlayAudioGUI(duration);
    g.run();

    amp = amplitude;
    ArrayList<double[]> chord = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    for(double freq : frequencies) {
        double[] note = StdAudio.tone(freq, duration);
        chord.add(note);
    }

    double[] chordCombined = new double[chord.get(0).length];
    for (int i = 0; i < chordCombined.length; i++) {
        for (double[] note : chord) {
            chordCombined[i] += note[i];
        }
        chordCombined[i] /= chord.size();
    }
    StdAudio.play(chordCombined);
}
```

I've never attempted multithreading before, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. When I run the code, It shows an empty window while it plays the chord, then afterwards displays the window properly. I'd like for it to display the window at the same time as playing the audio.

Here is my code for the window's class.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class PlayAudioGUI implements Runnable {
    private JFrame window;
    private JProgressBar prog;
    private double duration;
    private Timer t;

    class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        // This runs every few milliseconds, depending on the delay set below
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            prog.setValue(prog.getValue() + 1);
            // Stop the timer and hide the window when the progress bar
            // completes
            if (prog.getValue() == prog.getMaximum()) {
                t.stop();
                window.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public PlayAudioGUI(double duration) {
        this.window = new JFrame("Playing audio...");
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Setting up gridbag layout. I will add more components later.
        Container pane = this.window.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(30, 30, 30, 30);

        // Display the approximate duration
        String clippedDuration;
        if (Double.toString(duration).length() > 5) {
            clippedDuration = Double.toString(duration).substring(0, 4);
        } else {
            clippedDuration = Double.toString(duration);
        }
        String message = "Playing audio for " + clippedDuration + " seconds";
        pane.add(new JLabel(message), c);

        // Make a progressbar
        c.gridy = 1;
        this.prog = new JProgressBar();
        this.prog.setMinimum(0);
        this.prog.setMaximum(250);
        pane.add(this.prog, c);

        // More window management stuff
        this.window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.window.pack();
        this.window.setVisible(true);

        // Set up the timer
        ActionListener listener = new TimerListener();
        final int DELAY = (int) (4 * this.duration); // This works, I did the
                                                        // math :)
        t = new Timer(DELAY, listener);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: If anything confuses you in my answer, please ask.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

- The new dependent dialog window should be just that, a dialog such as a JDialog, not a new JFrame which is creating a whole separate application.
- You know that you should be doing your sound creation in a background thread, and your blank screen is being caused by just this problem, and yet I see no thread creation in your code -- why?
- Myself, I'd not use a Swing Timer, and poll data, but rather do all within a SwingWorker, within the SwingWorker's `doInBackground` method I'd update its progress state, and I'd add a PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker and monitor this state.
- As an aside, you will almost never want to create a Runnable class and then call its `run()` method. If you're creating the Runnable to allow it to run in a background thread, then you'd likely place it into a Thread and then call `start()` on the Thread. Since your code above should run on the Swing event thread, then if it is not being called from this thread, it should be queued on to it via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(myRunnable);`
- I'm not sure how you can get a progress value from your StdAudio library. If there's a way, then use it to set the SwingWorker's progress state via its `setProgress(...)` method. If not, then you could guess, I suppose or you may be better off using an indeterminate progress bar. I believe JProgressBar has a method called `setIndeterminate(true)` that would work for this.